# Where can I find emacs logs on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows

In this SO question [Emacs 23.1.50.1 hangs ramdomly for 6-8 seconds on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007329/emacs-23-1-50-1-hangs-ramdomly-for-6-8-seconds-on-windows-xp) the OP show logs from Emacs that may cause errors, where can I find those logs?

Comment: Those are "Process Monitor logs", and that same Q&A provided the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2007410